# Forced water base board heater

Tags: baseboard

I want to make the front of a forced hot water heater the back and the back the front, this I’d like to take the metal back off and build a new front, does the heater NEED the metal back?  Cabinets will be on the new back (current front). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, other than any support brackets holding the pipe/fin-tube up. The "new front" does need vents below and above the finned tubing to permit airflow for functional reasons.